# Microsoft ChatBot auto scroll stoped working

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I am using latest version of [Microsoft ChatBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), when i send or receive messages,

1. the display does not scroll down to the latest one
2. the entry bar is starting at the top of the window(not from the bottom of the window, attached image) not sure if this is the intended behaviour.

[image]

react component

```
class Layout extends Component {
render() {
return(
  <Aux>
    <main className="Container">
      <ReactWebChat
        botAvatarInitials= 'BOT'
        userAvatarInitials= 'USER'
        directLine={secret} 
        styleSet={styleSet}
      />
    </main>
  </Aux>
)
}}
```

Comment: Hi @Venuu. Which sample are you using? For example, if you were to use [full bundle](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/546fee4db3bb64ebff7bf9a2db61405c8d9b923e/samples/01.a.getting-started-full-bundle/index.html#L38), that has a line that takes focus.

Comment: @DanaV I am not using any samples i mean, i just implemented with a brand new react project. i have update my react component above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your `ReactWebChat` component in a `div`  and set the height and width of the `div` and its children in the css to get the conversation to scroll to the bottom and have the entry bar start at the bottom. See below for how your code should look.

#### React Webchat Component

```
class Layout extends Component {
render() {
return(
  <Aux>
    <main className="Container">
      <div id="webchat">
          <ReactWebChat
            botAvatarInitials= 'BOT'
            userAvatarInitials= 'USER'
            directLine={secret} 
            styleSet={styleSet}
          />
      </div>
    </main>
  </Aux>
)
}}
```

#### CSS

```
#webchat,
#webchat>* {
  height: 750px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: it is working with px but not working with %. I don't want to give static value there

Comment: If you want to use percent instead of a static pixel value, you need to set the height and width of the container. So if you have WebChat nested in a body tag, set the height and width of the body to 100% as well.